# How to stop WordPress creating URLs that don't exist

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, duplicates

I have a website that is constantly creating URLs that don't exist.

For example a category section that only has 2 pages in it, for some reason is allowing the creation of other URLs, e.g. http://www.example.com/products/page/11142/311355/909238/12807/

There is actually only one URL, e.g.: /page/2/

I have no idea why and how it is doing this, and would very much like some help please. Google is also indexing these pages with the made up numerical additions, and I would like to clear ASAP.

Comment: It sounds like either the rewrite rules are bad or whatever is creating the link is bad. You can view the rewrite rules using the Rewrite Rule  Inspector plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, I think it may also be a plugin issue, would you be able to offer additional help if required?

Comment: Just ask back here and someone should see it. Try disabling your plugins and then rebuild your rewrite rules to see if it clears the problem up.

Comment: Hi, I would do, however the plugin has a large amount of Properties in it, and I am reluctant to mess it all up. Are you available to hire

Comment: Define "allowing" ? How have you discovered said URLs?

Comment: Deactivating your plugin probably won't remove your options from the database. Look for [register_deactivation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) in the main plugin file to confirm, but it's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "URL that doesn't exist" URL's are just *possible* identifiers for pages on the internet. Every combination of characters as defined by the URL standarts is a valid URL.

You can't control what URLs people are using to find content, if they want to use URLs for content that do not exist (and maybe can't even exist) you have no way to stop them.